# Overriding FastAPI's HTTPException response body

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, starlette

I'm currently writing a few end points for an API in fastAPI.
I'm defining classes that extend fastapi's HTTPException.

The problem is that HTTPException returns a response body with an attribute called detail which will either be a string or a json structure depending on what object you pass to it as seem below.

```
{
  "detail": {
    "msg": "error message here"
  }
}


{   "detail": "error message here" }
```

I would like to override this behavior and let it respond with my own structure.

I'm aware that i can install custom exceptions using the exception handler decorator and have that return a JSONResponse object but this is not what i'm looking for.

Comment: You can simply return a python dict. FastAPI will turn that into json automatically.

Comment: @phyominh yes i am aware of this however the reason i want to go down this path is to implement a sort of standard into the api, that all errors will be exceptions, can be raised and caught

Comment: Can this https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/ help?

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I want to do something similar and any hint would be appreciated. Thank you in advance and regards

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 2):

One option is to [set the status code](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/response-change-status-code/) corresponding to your exception, and then return a custom response body.

Here is a simple toy example using this approach to workaround the issue at hand:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response, status

myapp = FastAPI()

@myapp.get("/")
async def app_func(response: Response, myparam: str):

    #end point code here

    valid_params = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
    if myparam not in valid_params:
        #Customize logic, status code, and returned dict as needed

        response.status_code = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST

        return {'message': 'Oh no! I failed (without detail key)'}

    
    response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    return {'message': 'Yay! I succeeded!'}
```

A full list of available status codes can be found [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/master/starlette/status.py).