# How to customise error response for a specific route in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-422

I want to make an `HTTP` endpoint in FastAPI that requires a specific `Header`, produces a custom `response` code when the `Header` is absent, as well as shows the `Header` as *required* in the OpenAPI docs generated by FastAPI.

For example, if I make this endpoint to require `some-custom-header`:

```py
@app.post("/")
async def fn(some_custom_header: str = Header(...)):
    pass
```

when a client request lacks `some-custom-header`, the server will produce a `response` with error code [`422 Unprocessable entity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422).  However I'd like to be able to change that to [`401 Unauthorized`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401). In other words, I would like to **customise the `RequestValidationError` for that specific route** in my API.

I thought a possible solution would be to use `Header(None)`, and do a test for `None` in the function body, but, unfortunately, this results in the OpenAPI docs indicating that the header is *optional*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1

If you didn't mind having the `Header` showing as `Optional` in [OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/first-steps/#interactive-api-docs), it would be as easy as follows:

```py
from fastapi import Header, HTTPException
@app.post("/")
def some_route(some_custom_header: Optional[str] = Header(None)):
    if not some_custom_header:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail="Unauthorized")
    return {"some-custom-header": some_custom_header}
```

### Option 2

However, since you would like the `Header` to appear as *required* in OpenAPI, you should override the default exception handler. [When a request contains invalid data, FastAPI internally raises a `RequestValidationError`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#override-the-default-exception-handlers). Thus, you need to override the `RequestValidationError`, which  [contains the body it received with invalid data](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-the-requestvalidationerror-body).

Since `RequestValidationError` is a sub-class of Pydantic's [`ValidationError`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/#error-handling), you can access the errors as shown in the link above, so that you can check whether your custom `Header` is included in the errors (if so, that means that is either missing from the request, or is not of `str` type), and hence, return your custom error response. If your custom `Header` (i.e., `some_custom_header` in the example below) is the only parameter in that specific endpoint, then it is **not** necessary to perform the check described above (and demosntrated below), as if a `RequestValidationError` was raised, it would be only for that parameter.

#### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Header, status
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

app = FastAPI()
routes_with_custom_exception = ['/']

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    if request.url.path in routes_with_custom_exception:
        # check whether the error relates to the `some_custom_header` parameter
        for err in exc.errors():
            if err['loc'][0] == 'header' and err['loc'][1] == 'some-custom-header':
                return JSONResponse(content={'401': 'Unauthorized'}, status_code=401)
            
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({'detail': exc.errors(), 'body': exc.body}),
    )

@app.get('/')
def some_route(some_custom_header: str = Header(...)):
    return {'some-custom-header': some_custom_header}
```

### Option 3

Another solution would be to use [Sub-Application(s)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/) (inspired by the discussion [here](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1174)). You could create a sub app (or more if needed) and mount it to the main app—which would include the route(s) that require the custom `Header`; hence, overriding the `exception_handler` for `RequestValidationError` in that sub app would only apply to those routes, without having to check for the `request.url.path`, as demonstrated in the previous solution—and have the main app with the remaining routes as usual. As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/sub-applications/#mounting-a-fastapi-application):

> **Mounting a FastAPI application**
>
> "Mounting" means adding a completely "independent" application in a
> specific path, that then takes care of handling everything under that
> path, with the *path operations* declared in that sub-application.

#### Example

**Note:** If you mounted the sub-application (i.e., `subapi` in the example below) using the `'/'` path, you wouldn't be able to access the routes of `subapi` at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs, as the API docs on that page will only include the routes of the main app. Also, it would interfere with the `'/'` route of the main API (if such a route exists in the main API), and since [**endpoints' order matters in FastAPI**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74498663/17865804), issuing a request to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` would actually call the corresponding route of the main API (as demonstrated below). Thus, you would rather mount `subapi` using a different path, e.g., `'/sub'`, as demonstrated below, and access the sub API docs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/docs. A Python requests example is also given below, demonstrating how to test the app.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Header
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()

@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return {'message': 'Hello from main API'}
    

subapi = FastAPI()
   
@subapi.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    # if there are other parameters defined in the endpoint other than
    # `some_custom_header`, then perform a check, as demonstrated in Option 2
    return JSONResponse(content={'401': 'Unauthorized'}, status_code=401)

    
@subapi.get('/')
async def sub_api_route(some_custom_header: str = Header(...)):
    return {'some-custom-header': some_custom_header}    


app.mount('/sub', subapi)
```

##### Test the example above

```py
import requests

# Test main API
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

r = requests.get(url=url)
print(r.status_code, r.json())

# Test sub API
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/sub/'

r = requests.get(url=url)
print(r.status_code, r.json())

headers = {'some-custom-header': 'this is some custom header'}
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code, r.json())
```

### Option 4

A further solution would be to use an [`APIRouter`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter) with a [custom `APIRoute` class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router), as demonstrated in Option 2 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804), and handle the request inside a `try-except` block (which will be used to catch `RequestValidationError` exceptions), as described in [FastAPI's documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#accessing-the-request-body-in-an-exception-handler). If an exception occurs, you can handle the error as desired, and return a custom respone.

#### Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Response, Request, Header, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from fastapi.exceptions import RequestValidationError
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from typing import Callable

class ValidationErrorHandlingRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            try:
                return await original_route_handler(request)
            except RequestValidationError as e:
                # if there are other parameters defined in the endpoint other than
                # `some_custom_header`, then perform a check, as demonstrated in Option 2
                raise HTTPException(status_code=401, detail='401 Unauthorized')
                            
        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=ValidationErrorHandlingRoute)


@app.get('/')
async def main():
    return {'message': 'Hello from main API'}
    

@router.get('/custom')
async def custom_route(some_custom_header: str = Header(...)):
    return {'some-custom-header': some_custom_header}


app.include_router(router)
```

##### Test the example above

```py
import requests

# Test main API
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

r = requests.get(url=url)
print(r.status_code, r.json())

# Test custom route
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/custom'

r = requests.get(url=url)
print(r.status_code, r.json())

headers = {'some-custom-header': 'this is some custom header'}
r = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
print(r.status_code, r.json())
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, this looks like a solution.  It's a bit of a shame that it has to be done in a 'global' exception handler, rather than something specific to the route that's generating the error, but it'll do the job.

Comment: @RobGilton The answer above has been further updated with more options. Please have a look.