# How do I integrate custom exception handling with the FastAPI exception handling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, fastapi

Python version 3.9, FastAPI version 0.78.0

I have a custom function that I use for application exception handling. When requests run into internal logic problems, i.e I want to send an HTTP response of 400 for some reason, I call a utility function.

```
@staticmethod
def raise_error(error: str, code: int) -> None:
    logger.error(error)
    raise HTTPException(status_code=code, detail=error)
```

Not a fan of this approach. So I look at

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, status
from fastapi.respones import JSONResponse

class ExceptionCustom(HTTPException):
    pass


def exception_404_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, content={"message": "404"})


app.add_exception_handler(ExceptionCustom, exception_404_handler)
```

The problem I run into with the above approach is the inability to pass in the message as an argument.

Any thoughts on the whole topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your custom exception can have any custom attributes that you want. Let's say you write it this way:

```py
class ExceptionCustom(HTTPException):
    pass
```

in your custom handler, you can do something like

```py
def exception_404_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, content={"message": exc.detail})
```

Then, all you need to do is to raise the exception this way:

```py
raise ExceptionCustom(status_code=404, detail='error message')
```

Note that you are creating a handler for this specific `ExceptionCustom`. If all you need is the message, you can write something more generic:

```py
class MyHTTPException(HTTPException):
    pass
```

```py
def my_http_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=exc.status_code, content={"message": exc.detail})
```

```py
app.add_exception_handler(MyHTTPException, my_http_exception_handler)
```

This way you can raise any exception, with any status code and any message and have the `message` in your JSON response.

There's a detailed explanation on [FastAPI docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/)

Answer (score 6):

### Option 1

You could add [custom exception handlers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#install-custom-exception-handlers), and use attributes in your `Exception` class (i.e., `MyException(Exception)` in the example below), in order to pass a custom message or variables. The exception handler (in the example below, that is, `my_exception_handler()` with the `@app.exception_handler(MyException)` decorator) will handle the exception as you wish and return your custom message. For more options, please have a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) as well.

##### Working Example

In order to trigger the exception in the example below, call the `/items/{item_id}` endpoint using an `item_id` that is not present in the `items` dictionary.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, status
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse


class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, item_id: str):
        self.item_id = item_id


app = FastAPI()

items = {"foo": "The Foo Wrestlers"}


@app.exception_handler(MyException)
async def my_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: MyException):
    return JSONResponse(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, 
        content={"message": f"Item for '{exc.item_id}' cannot be found." })


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: str):
    if item_id not in items:
        raise MyException(item_id=item_id)
    return {"item": items[item_id]}
```

In case you wouldn't like using the `@app.exception_handler()` decorator, you could remove the decorator from the `my_exception_handler()` funciton and instead use the `add_exception_handler()` method to add the handler to the `app` instance. Example:

```py
app.add_exception_handler(MyException, my_exception_handler)
```

Another way to add the exception handler to the `app` instance would be to use the `exception_handlers` parameter of the FastAPI class, as demonstrated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804). Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804).

### Option 2

You could always [use `HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#use-httpexception) to return HTTP responses with custom errors to the client (as well as [add custom headers to the HTTP error](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#add-custom-headers)).

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()

items = {"foo": "The Foo Wrestlers"}


@app.get("/items/{item_id}")
async def read_item(item_id: str):
    if item_id not in items:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="Item not found")
    return {"item": items[item_id]}
```

Comment: How does this work ? I am also seeing this but not sure what is the flow of execution here.