# Logs on server side for pydantic type inference in FastAPI

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-422

As is the general case with FastAPI, if a request doesn't correspond to the Pydantic model we get a `422 Unprocessable entity` error and the response is visible on the client side.

Is there a way to get the log this on the server side?

example:

```py
class Model(BaseModel):
    id: int
    name: str
    surname: str
    
@app.post("/", status_code=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
async def create_student(student:Model):
    #Some functionality being done
    pass
```

In the above case if the request is

```json
{
  "name":"John",
  "surname":"Smith"
}
```

The fastapi throws an error on client side with status code 422. Is it possible to catch the error in the server side and write some logs as to what was the input request etc.

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804).

Comment: Alternatively, you can use a middleware or APIRoute class, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804).

Comment: Thanks @Chris most of the approaches solve the need, I have closed the question.