# Pydantic with FastAPI: How to customise the message for "422 Unprocessable Entity" error?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

When sending wrong parameters, how can I customise the "422 Unprocessable Entity" error message to receive, instead of:

```
{"detail": [
{
"loc": [
. . . . . .
],
"msg": "field required",
"type": "value_error.missing"
}
]}
```

something more simple like this:

```
{"status": "failed", "error": "value_error.missing"}
```

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804).

Comment: I tested the first link and it's fine, is what I wanted. But all links are useful to me. Thank you so much!