# How to raise custom exceptions in a FastAPI middleware?

Tags: python, python-3.x, fastapi, middleware, starlette

I have a simple FastAPI setup with a custom middleware class inherited from [**`BaseHTTPMiddleware`**](https://www.starlette.io/middleware/#basehttpmiddleware). Inside this middleware class, I need to terminate the execution flow under certain conditions. So, I created a custom exception class named `CustomError` and ***`raised`*** the exception.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from starlette.middleware.base import (
    BaseHTTPMiddleware,
    RequestResponseEndpoint
)
from starlette.responses import JSONResponse, Response

app = FastAPI()


class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message


class CustomMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    def execute_custom_logic(self, request: Request):
        raise CustomError("This is from `CustomMiddleware`")

    async def dispatch(
            self,
            request: Request,
            call_next: RequestResponseEndpoint,
    ) -> Response:
        self.execute_custom_logic(request=request)
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response


app.add_middleware(CustomMiddleware)


@app.exception_handler(CustomError)
async def custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: CustomError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=418,
        content={"message": exc.message},
    )


@app.get(path="/")
def root_api():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}
```

Unfortunately, FastAPI couldn't handle the **`CustomError`** even though I added **`custom_exception_handler(...)`** handler.

---

#### Questions

1. What is the *FastAPI* way to handle such situations?
2. Why is my code not working?

**Versions**

- FastAPI - 0.95.2
- Python - 3.8.13

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The obvious way would be to [raise an `HTTPException`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code); however, in a FastAPI/Starlette middleware, this wouldn't work, leading to `Exception in ASGI application` error on server side, and hence, an `Internal Server Error` would be returned to the client.

### Option 1 - Using `middleware` and `try/except` block

You could use a `try/except` block to handle the [custom exception](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) raised in your custom function. Once the error is raised, you could return a `JSONResponse` (or custom `Response`, if you prefer), including the `msg` (and any other arguments) from `CustomException`, as well as the desired `status_code` (in the example given below, `500` status code is used, which could be replaced by the status code of your choice).

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse

app = FastAPI()


class CustomException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg: str):
        self.msg = msg
 
 
def exec_custom_logic(request: Request):
    raise CustomException(msg='Something went wrong') 

    
@app.middleware("http")
async def custom_middleware(request: Request, call_next):
    try:    
        exec_custom_logic(request)
    except CustomException as e:
        return JSONResponse(status_code=500, content={'message': e.msg})
        
    return await call_next(request)
    
    
@app.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    return 'OK'
```

### Option 2 - Using an `APIRouter` with a custom `APIRoute` class

You could use an [`APIRouter`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/bigger-applications/#apirouter) with a [custom `APIRoute` class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-request-and-route/#custom-apiroute-class-in-a-router), as demonstrated in Option 4 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804), and either handle the custom exception inside a `try/except` block (as shown in the previous option above), or raise an `HTTPException` directly. The advantages of this approach are: (1) you could raise an `HTTPException` directly, and hence, there is no need for using `try/except` blocks, and (2) you could add to the `APIRouter` only those routes that you would like to handle that way, using, for instance, the `@router.get()` decorator, while the rest of the routes could be added to the `app` instance, using, for example, the `@app.get()` decorator.

##### Working Example

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Response, Request, HTTPException
from fastapi.routing import APIRoute
from typing import Callable


def exec_custom_logic(request: Request):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail='Something went wrong')
    

class CustomAPIRoute(APIRoute):
    def get_route_handler(self) -> Callable:
        original_route_handler = super().get_route_handler()

        async def custom_route_handler(request: Request) -> Response:
            exec_custom_logic(request)
            return await original_route_handler(request)
       
        return custom_route_handler


app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter(route_class=CustomAPIRoute)


@router.get('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    return 'OK'
    
app.include_router(router)
```

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI's custom exception handlers are not handling middleware level exceptions. Although this is not stated anywhere in the docs, there is [part about HTTPException](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/#raise-an-httpexception-in-your-code), which says that you can raise `HTTPException` *if you are inside a utility function that you are calling inside of your path operation function*. `HTTPException` has [default exception handler](https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/master/fastapi/exception_handlers.py#L10) that acts absolutely the same as custom exception handlers do.

You can either handle your error (with `try/except`) within the same middleware or have separate middleware e.g. `ExceptionHandlerMiddleware` (but you'll have to keep the order of middleware chain correct).

Comment: Can you show an example?