# Add top level field for every response in FastAPI

Tags: json, python-3.x, fastapi

I'm migrating an existing Flask application to FastAPI and I'm trying to find a simple way to migrate this (awkward) existing behavior:

currently every API output is overridden to look like this

```
{
   "data" : {# the actual API output}
}
```

The best shot I gave so far is to have a 'templated' APIOutput class

```
class APIOutput(Generic[T]):
   data: T
```

as output for every path operation.

I would like to instead not having to bother with that, let the path operations return what they're supposed to do, and add an overrider only once to add this extra layer.

Comment: If you are looking for changing the response using a `middleware` or `APIRouter`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73464007/17865804). You might find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269047/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) helpful as well.