# FastAPI: return an appropriate error message and status for unhandled exceptions

Tags: python, fastapi

I would like my FastAPI app to always send detailed error messages in the response, even for unhandled exceptions.

I have looked at the docs for this (https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/handling-errors/) but I'm struggling to make it work for my use case.

In the examples below, endpoints /a and /b return the correct status code and error message to the client. /a raises an HTTPException directly, and /b raises it via the `specific_error_handler` function.

However, /c does not work as I expect. I would expect that the TypeError raised by /c would trigger the HTTPException raised by `generic_error_handler`. Instead, I get `Internal Server Error` with a status code of 500 in the client.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException

app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/a")
async def endpoint_a():
    raise HTTPException(status_code=501, detail="error occurred for endpoint a")


@app.get("/b")
async def endpoint_b():
    1 / 0  # unhandled ZeroDivisionError


@app.get("/c")
async def endpoint_c():
    1 + "1"  # unhandled TypeError


@app.exception_handler(ZeroDivisionError)
async def specific_error_handler(request, exc):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=501, detail=f"ZeroDivisionError occurred: {exc}")


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def generic_error_handler(request, exc):
    raise HTTPException(status_code=501, detail=f"unhandled Exception occurred: {exc}")
```

I can get around this by wrapping the code in /c in a try/except block, but this seems unpythonic. I don't want to have to wrap every single endpoint this way, I would rather have unhandled errors dealt with by a custom exception handler. How can I do this?

Comment: Have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61596911/catch-exception-globally-in-fastapi and, in more detail, the comment linking to using a custom route class? https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/how-to/custom-request-and-route/#accessing-the-request-body-in-an-exception-handler

Comment: In addition to the links provided above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269047/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77626671/17865804). Further related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804)