# FastAPI custom exceptions handler not working

Tags: python, fastapi, fastapi-middleware

I'm implementing custom exceptions in middleware and I want to raise an exception and expecting a JSON response with error message and code, when condition fails as mentioned below in middleware . But receiving INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Using version : fastapi[all]==0.99.0

```
# main.py

from fastapi import FastAPI
from starlette.middleware.base import BaseHTTPMiddleware
from exceptions import CustomException
from handlers import custom_exception_handler

app = FastAPI()

# Middleware function
class ValueCheckMiddleware(BaseHTTPMiddleware):
    async def dispatch(self, request, call_next):
        # Check the value in the request
        value = request.headers.get("X-Value")
        if value != "1":
            raise CustomException()
        # Call the next middleware or route handler
        response = await call_next(request)
        return response

# Register middleware
app.add_middleware(ValueCheckMiddleware)

# Register custom exception handler
app.add_exception_handler(CustomException, custom_exception_handler)

# Route
@app.get("/")
async def read_root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}



# handlers.py
from fastapi import HTTPException, Request, JSONResponse
from exceptions import CustomException

async def custom_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: CustomException) -> JSONResponse:
    return JSONResponse(status_code=exc.status_code, content={"detail": exc.detail})



# exceptions.py
from fastapi import HTTPException

class CustomException(HTTPException):
    def __init__(self, detail="Value is not one", status_code=400):
        super().__init__(status_code=status_code, detail=detail)
```

I want a json response when there is an exception in middleware.
But getting INTERNAL SERVER ERROR

Expectation: I want a json response when there is an exception in middleware..

Comment: What's in your server logs? Does the traceback point to the `raise CustomException()` line?

Comment: In addition to the link provided in the banner above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76269047/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71682274/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70954531/17865804)

Comment: @Chris Yeah I checked the provided answers, and I can achieve the expectations using these methods, but I'm looking for a very specific problem. The problem is I can raise custom exceptions in utility functions or all other services, but I can't raise it inside class-based middleware without using try/except block. That's the main problem. Any suggestions here ?

Comment: @Gaberocksall Yes traceback points to my CustomException() but there is some issue with while raising it and returning response

Here are the logs : [Link](https://notepad.link/b8tM3)