# How can I implement customized exception handling for HTTP status codes 422, 400, and 500 in FastAPI when using routers?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am not able to handle customized exception for request body, 422 exception is directly rasing from `fastapi` itself

I tried using:

```
app = FastAPI()

@app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError)
async def validation_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: RequestValidationError):
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=status.HTTP_422_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY,
        content=jsonable_encoder({"detail": exc.errors(), "body": exc.body}),
    )

app.include_router(router)
app.add_exception_handler(RequestValidationError, validation_exception_handler)
```

But still Iam not able to handle customized exception

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71800464/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72833284/17865804) as well

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in your code where you are trying to use `jsonable_encoder` on the `exc.errors()` and `exc.body` objects. The `exc.errors()` method returns a list of error dictionaries, and the `exc.body` attribute is a dictionary containing the parsed request body.

Use `JSONResponse()` instead of `json_decoder()`

Comment: When a validation error occurs while processing a request in FastAPI application, the custom exception handler I defined with @app.exception_handler(RequestValidationError) should be invoked automatically. Instead of that exception being raised and displayed directly in the Swagger UI